# How to overload operator on type erasure'd generic type? Or another approach altogether?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, type-erasure

### Preface: The actual problem statement

My original problem is pretty simple: How can I have a general container for scalar types(arithmetic types), and other classes like Matrix classes, Vector classes, Tensor classes, and have it behave correctly as if I did scalar+Matrix, MatrixVector, TensorMatrix, scalar+scalar, etc.

### How I'm trying to solve it

I'm trying to write a type erasure class. I'm not using `boost::type_erasure::any`. This is for my own exercise and I believe that using that library is unnecessary for this small purpose.

### The code

```
class var{
public:
    template <typename T>
    var(T val) : self_(std::make_unique<model<T> >(std::move(val))) {}
private:
    friend var operator+(const var& lhs, const var& rhs);

    class concept{
    public:
        virtual ~concept() = default;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<concept> copy_() const = 0;
    };

    template <typename T>
    class model final : concept {
        model(T x) : data_(std::move(x)) {}
        std::unique_ptr<concept> copy_() const override{
            return std::make_unique<model>(*this);
        }
        T data_;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<concept> self_;
};

var operator+(const var& lhs, const var& rhs){
    ... // do something here
}
```

## What I *want*

So say we have something like:

```
var v1(3); // implicitly <int>
var v2(5.2); // implicitly <double> or <float>
v1 + v2; // implicitly <double> with value 8.2
```

while the same class can take care of:

```
var v1(std::string("hello "));
var v2(std::string("world!"));
v1 + v2; // implicitly <std::string> with value "hello world!"
```

Meanwhile, I can have a vector of these things:

```
vector<var> v;
v.emplace_back(std::string("hello ")); // no error
v.emplace_back(3); // no error either
```

### What I've tried

I had the idea of providing an adder:

#### #1: Templating Concept too, for get_data()

```
class var{
...
private:
    // Also make concept templated!
    template <typename T>
    class concept{
    public:
        virtual ~concept() = default;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<concept> copy_() const = 0;

        virtual T get_data(); 
    };

    template <typename T>
    class model final : concept<T> {
        model(T x) : data_(std::move(x)) {}
        std::unique_ptr<concept<T>> copy_() const override{
            return std::make_unique<model>(*this);
        }

        std::unique_ptr<concept<T>> adder(std::unique_ptr<concept<T>> rhs){
            return data_ + rhs->get_data();
        }
        T data_;
    };
    // this defeats the purpose of type erasure!
    std::unique_ptr<concept<T>> self_;
    ...
}

var operator+(const var& lhs, const var& rhs){
    return { lhs.self_->get_data() + rhs.self->get_data() };
}
```

#### #2: Trying to use inheritance polymorphism for adder()

```
class var{
...
    class concept{
    public:
        virtual ~concept() = default;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<concept> copy_() const = 0;
        // virtual ??? get_data(); What do I return here?
        //
        // template <typename T>
        // virtual T get_data(); // virtual cannot be defined on function templates!
    };

    template <typename T>
    class model final : concept {
        ...
        std::unique_ptr<concept> add(std::unique_ptr<concept> rhs){
            return data_ + rhs->get_data();
        }
        T data_;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<concept> self_;
};

var operator+(const var& lhs, const var& rhs){
    return { lhs.self_->adder(rhs.self_) };
}
```

If perhaps type erasure isn't the right approach for this kind of problem, what should I do? (I want to avoid combinatorial # of overloads) Otherwise, is there a solution for this *with* the current setup?

For an explanation of the background, **I'm trying to get scalar multiplication with a matrix(vice versa), and matrix multiplication with a matrix, and scalar multiplication with a scalar.** (This obviously goes beyond only addition) In this case, they're all numerical, but in this, I added a `std::string` example for clarity.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need type-erasure to provide these operators for matrix. What is your matrix class? Do you have a `scalar` class or do you simply refer to arithmetic types (`int`, `double`, ...)? I think you should  present your original problem in details, rather than this attempt to solve it.

Comment: It is a well known problem with no solution. You either have a quadratic number of overloads, or have all your calculations performed in terms of a a single universal type that all other types are convertible to, or some form of compromise between the two.

Comment: @Holt My original problem is pretty simple: How can I have a general container for scalar types(arithmetic types), and other classes like Matrix classes, Vector classes, Tensor classes, and have it behave correctly as if I did scalar+Matrix, Matrix*Vector, Tensor*Matrix, scalar+scalar, etc.

Comment: You can't, unless you write scalar+Matrix, Matrix\*Vector, Tensor\*Matrix, scalar+scalar etc yourself, *and* write code that dispatches to the correct function according to your dynamic argument types.

Comment: Highly suggest what Holt suggested: present your problem instead of your attempted solution

Comment: @PasserBy The original problem is stated 2 comments above, but I'll add it into my question.

Comment: `#define var auto` makes your "what I want" work.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Oh yeah, you're right. That was a bad example, I'll edit it with another example.